# image runs properly using docker run -dit, but exits using docker stack deploy -c

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I've been porting a web service to docker recently. As mentioned in the title, I'm encountering a weird scenario where in when I run it using docker run -dit, the service runs in the background, but when I use a docker-compose.yml, the service exits.

To be clearer, I have this entrypoint in my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/data/start-service.sh"]
```

this is the code of start-service.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor=/data/vassals/ --daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log
/etc/init.d/nginx start
exec "$@";
```

as you can see, I'm just starting uwsgi and nginx here in this shell script. The last line (exec) is just make the script accept a parameter and keep it running. Then I run this using:

```
docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 --name=web_server webserver /bin/bash
```

As mentioned, the service runs OK and I can access the webservice.

Now, I tried to deploy this using a docker-compose.yml, but the service keeps on exiting/shutting down. I attempted to retrieve the logs, but I have no success. All I can see from doing **docker ps -a** is it runs for a second or 2 (or 3), and then exits.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web_server:
    image: webserver
    entrypoint:
      - /data/start-service.sh
      - /bin/bash
    ports:
      - "8089:8080"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 2048M
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  - webnet
```

The entrypoint entry in the yml file is just to make sure that start-service.sh script will be ran with /bin/bash as its parameter, to keep the service running. But again, the service shuts down.

Comment: can you provide logs from these commands? `docker service ls` `docker service logs <service-name>`

Comment: @yamenk - thanks for the reply. I did those commands already but I did not get any result; neither in stdin/terminal nor a file in the current working directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` will exit without a proper tty. Since you execute `bash` via `exec` it becomes PID 1. Whenever PID 1 exits the container is stopped.

To prevent this add `tty: true` to the service's description in your compose file. This is basically the same thing as you do with `-t` with the `docker run` command.